# Why is there still white space between these divs in all browsers except Chrome?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <title>Okmulgee Online</title>
        <base href="/home.cshtml" />
        <link href="/Styles/main.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <![if ! lte IE 8]><link href="/Styles/not_lte_IE8.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link href="/Styles/lte_IE8.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
        <link href="/Plugins/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="/Images/Site_Icon/Scribe.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

        <script src="/Resources/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Plugins/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Plugins/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Plugins/accounting.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/PluginConfigurations.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topBar"></div>
        <div id="mainWrapper">
            <div id="bannerBar"></span><img alt="Okmulgee Banner Image" src="/Images/City_Images/banner.jpg" /></div>
            <img id="colorFade" alt="Color Fading Background Image" src="/Images/Background_Images/GreenFadeBackground.jpg" />
            <div id="btnWrapper">
                    <!--Buttons For Visitor Type Drop Down Links *START*-->
                <div id="residentsDDL" class="DDL visType residentsDD"><img src="/Images/Background_Images/BrownButton.jpg" alt="Btn Img" /><div class="btnText">Residents</div></div><!--
             --><div id="businessesDDL" class="DDL visType businessesDD"><img src="/Images/Background_Images/BrownButton.jpg" alt="Btn Img" /><div class="btnText">Businesses</div></div><!--
             --><div id="visitorsDDL" class="DDL visType"><img src="/Images/Background_Images/BrownButton.jpg" alt="Btn Img" /><div class="btnText">Visitors</div></div><!--
                   <!--Buttons For Visitor Type Drop Down Links *END*--><!--
                    <!--Buttons For Category Type Drop Down Links *START*--><!--
             --><div id="cityDDL" class="DDL groupType"><img src="/Images/Background_Images/GreyButton.jpg" alt="Btn Img" /><div class="btnText">City of Okmulgee</div></div><!--
             --><div id="mainStreetDDL" class="DDL groupType"><img src="/Images/Background_Images/GreyButton.jpg" alt="Btn Img" /><div class="btnText">Main Street</div></div><!--
             --><div id="organizationsDDL" class="DDL groupType"><img src="/Images/Background_Images/GreyButton.jpg" alt="Btn Img" /><div class="btnText">Organizations</div></div><!--
             --><div id="oadcDDL" class="DDL groupType"><img src="/Images/Background_Images/GreyButton.jpg" alt="Btn Img" /><div class="btnText">OADC</div></div>
                  <!--Buttons For Category Type Drop Down Links *END*-->
            </div><!--
         --><div id="DBWrapper">
                <div class="DDB residentsDD" id="residentsDDB">Goo'day Mate!</div><!--
             --><div class="DDB businessesDD" id="businessesDDB"></div>
            </div>




            <p class="footer">&copy; 2013 City Of Okmulgee. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And My CSS:**

```
body
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

#topBar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #57bf2a;
    margin: auto;
}

div#bannerBar
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

div#bannerBar img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#mainWrapper
{
    width: 75%;
    width: 840px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
    behavior: url(/Resources/PIE.htc);
    /*Delete This*/height: 600px;
}

p.footer
{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: .8em;
}

img#colorFade
{
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}

.DDL
{
    position: relative;
    width: 119px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

.DDL img
{
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.DDL.visType
{
    background-color: #bb9191;
    border-right: 2px inset #9d6f6f;
    color: #37691f;
}

.DDL.groupType
{
    background-color: #6b6b6b;
    border-right: 2px inset #4b4b4b;
    color: #0b3773;
}

.DDL .btnText
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    /*font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;*/
    /*font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;*/
    font-family: Georgia, Serif;
    font-size: .7em; /*was .9*/
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding: 7px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

.btnText:hover
{
    color: #fff;
}

.DDL:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #63bf5f;
}

.DDL img
{
    opacity: .6;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 60);
}

#oadcDDL
{
    border-right: none;
}

#btnWrapper
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}

#DBWrapper
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
}

.DDB
{
    background-color: #63bf5f;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    margin: 0px;
}

#residentsDDB
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    border-left: 0px none;
}

#businessesDDB
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**And My js File:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //Broken image error handling
    $("img").error(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });

    //ddl functions
    $(".DDL").mouseover(function () {
        //$(this).find("img").css("display", "none");
        $(this).find("img").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
    $(".DDL").mouseout(function () {
        //$(this).find("img").css("display", "initial");
        $(this).find("img").css("visibility", "visible");
    });

    //residentsDDL Control
    $("#residentsDDL").mouseover(function () {
        $("#residentsDDB").css("display", "block");
    });
    $(".residentsDD").mouseover(function () {
        $("#residentsDDB").css("display", "block");
        $("#residentsDDL").css("background-color", "#63bf5f");
        $("#residentsDDL").find("img").css("visibility", "hidden");

    });
    $(".residentsDD").mouseout(function () {
        $("#residentsDDB").css("display", "none");
        $("#residentsDDL").find("img").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#residentsDDL").css("background-color", "#bb9191");
    });

    //businessesDDL Control
    $("#businessesDDL").mouseover(function () {
        $("#businessesDDB").css("display", "block");
    });
    $(".businessesDD").mouseover(function () {
        $("#businessesDDB").css("display", "block");
        $("#businessesDDL").css("background-color", "#63bf5f");
        $("#businessesDDL").find("img").css("visibility", "hidden");

    });
    $(".businessesDD").mouseout(function () {
        $("#businessesDDB").css("display", "none");
        $("#businessesDDL").find("img").css("visibility", "visible");
        $("#businessesDDL").css("background-color", "#bb9191");
    });
});
```

I hate to post so much code for something so simple, but as you can see, I have eliminated the white space between the concerning elements by placing html comments between the divs.

I have also ensured that there are no margins for any of the concerning elements, however, I still see this in both IE and Firefox (if it were just IE, I could use conditional comments to solve this issue):

[image]

While in Chrome, I see it as I would like all browsers to render it (like always, only Chrome really gets it right):

[image]

Where is this white space coming from? What can I do to get rid of it, cross-browser? (I must also adhere to IE8, if that is relevant).

Comment: Do you have a link to a working website with the menu problem?

Comment: @Supplement It is not a working site yet. It is in construction.

Comment: Put your code in a fiddle so we can see your problem, live.

Comment: This is a job for the browser's dev tools. You have fully functioning dev tools in FF and IE which can tell you the layout for any element on the page. Instead you're asking us to try to guess why that space exists based on the limited code you provided.

Comment: I was going to type up the same thing, pretty much it would be a lot easier to look at if there was a live link because than you could just user dev tools.

Comment: @Terry, here it is in fiddle but it won't render properly.http://jsfiddle.net/t5StK/

Comment: It's probably because your images are using the default `display: inline` property. Try adding `display: block` to `.DDL img`

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and CSS for the entire page please

Comment: There are two tags with id `mainStreetDDL`. Ids should be unique.

Comment: FWIW, Chrome's `display:inline-block; overflow:hidden;` layout is broken. The other browsers are correct.

Comment: @SimeVidas Well, only Chrome's dev tools are ever useful and even if I were debugging in Chrome, I wouldn't know how to tell what was causing the white space, but perhaps you should tell me, then I'll know how :) (Also, I wasn't asking anyone to 'guess' why it was there, I was asking if anyone 'knew' what was causing it, because I couldn't figure it out).

Comment: @Arjan It is not a finished site. That element was copy pasted and I haven't changed the id yet. Thanks for pointing it out, so I don't forget about it, though :)

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed I have edited my post to include ALL of the HTML and CSS for the entire page.

Comment: Also, I guess you will need my jQuery to make it work properly, so I will now add that to my post, as well.

Comment: @VoidKing The dev tools in Firefox and IE are just as good to solve your issue. You have to select the affected elements and inspect their layout values (the computed margins, padding, and borders). Why don't you put the site online? You've posted all code already.

Comment: @SimeVidas You're right about the dev tools (in fact that's how I ended up narrowing down which element actually added the white space). Don't get me wrong, I use the dev tools all the time, but in Chrome. I am afraid I just don't know where to find anything in FF's or IE's versions of this tool. As for why I don't just put the site online: I guess I don't understand where I would put it since we haven't signed up for a different web host than we are currently using (the new web host needs to support WebMatrix). Are you talking about just throwing it in jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @VoidKing I assumed that you had a personal site which you could use. (It is implied that web developers have at least one personal hosting account which they use for personal web sites, testing, etc.)

Comment: Can you give me the image dimensions for your images?  I will make placeholder ones while I look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the `#btnWrapper` div was forced to have a greater line-height than necessary in IE and FF. Adding a line-height of (at most) .7em proved to close up the white space (kind of funny because the actual buttons themselves (which are contained within the `#btnWrapper` div) are rendered with a line height of 1.3em, so this makes no real sense to me, but...).

So in short I simply added said property to the `#btnWrapper` rule, like so:

```
#btnWrapper
{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: .7em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your images are using the default `display: inline` property which applies line-height to the image, usually resulting in a bit of whitespace at the bottom of the image.

Try adding `display: block` to `.DDL img`:

```
.DDL img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: That, or `vertical-align:bottom`.

Comment: This answer did not solve the issue.  Adding `display: block` (and even trying `vertical-align: bottom`) showed no changes in the display of this page, at all.  I will edit my post to include ALL of the HTML and CSS now. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Also, I guess you will need my jQuery to make it work properly, so I will now add that to my post, as well.

Comment: I am going to look at this in a little bit for you.